# FastAPI with MySQL CRUD 422 Validation Error

Tags: python, mysql, fastapi, crud

I am a fastapi begginer, and i want to implement MySQL CRUD with FastAPI, but i get some error.

With code, i can use fastapi swagger ui to do CRUD and get 200 successful response, however, i will also recieve 422 error message, i dont know why will i recieve this and how to solve.

```
422  Validation Error
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "loc": [
        "string",
        0
      ],
      "msg": "string",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

db.py (working good)

```
import mysql.connector
from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def get_db_connection():
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(
        host='localhost',
        user="root",
        password="",
        autocommit=True
    )
    db = connection.cursor()

    try:
        yield db
        print("connect_success")
    finally:
        db.close()
        connection.close()
   
def create_db(db_name):
    try:
        with get_db_connection() as db:
            db.execute(f"CREATE DATABASE {db_name}")
            print(f"successful create database : {db_name}")
    except mysql.connector.Error as error:
        print(f"Error creating new databases: {error}")

def create_table(db_name,table_name):
    try:
        with get_db_connection() as db:
            employeetbl_create = f"""CREATE TABLE {db_name}.{table_name} (
                                `empid` INT NOT NULL ,
                                `empname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
                                `department` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
                                `salary` INT NULL,
                                PRIMARY KEY (`empid`))"""
            db.execute(employeetbl_create)
            print(f"successful create table {table_name}")
    except mysql.connector.Error as error:
        print(f"Error creating new databases: {error}")

def insert_table(db_name, table_name,empid,empname,department,salary):
    try:
        with get_db_connection() as db:
        
            employeetbl_insert = f"""INSERT INTO  {db_name}.{table_name} (
                empid,
                empname,
                department,
                salary)
                VALUES  (%s,%s, %s, %s)"""
 
            data = [
                (empid,empname,department,salary)
            ]
        
            db.executemany(employeetbl_insert, data)
           
            print(f"Successfully inserted data into table {table_name}")
    except mysql.connector.Error as error:
        print(f"Error inserting data into table: {error}")

def read_table(db_name,table_name,range):
    try:
        with get_db_connection() as db:
            select = f"""SELECT {range} FROM {db_name}.{table_name}"""
            db.execute(select)
            obj = db.fetchall()
            for items in obj:
                print(items)  
 
            print(f"successful read data from  {table_name}")
            return obj
    except mysql.connector.Error as error:
        print(f"Error Cant read data from  {table_name} : {error}")

def update_table(db_name, table_name, want_update, new_value, condition_column, condition_value):
    try:
        with get_db_connection() as db:
            update_query = f"""UPDATE {db_name}.{table_name}
                               SET {want_update} = {new_value}
                               WHERE {condition_column} = {condition_value}"""
            db.execute(update_query)
            print(f"Successfully updated data in {table_name} -> column : {want_update}")
    except mysql.connector.Error as error:
        print(f"Error updating data in {table_name} -> column : {want_update}: {error}")

def delete_table(db_name,table_name,condition_column, condition_value):
    try:
        with get_db_connection() as db:
            select = f""" DELETE FROM {db_name}.{table_name}\
                           WHERE {condition_column} = {condition_value}"""
            db.execute(select)
            print(f"successful delete data:  {table_name}")
    except mysql.connector.Error as error:
        print(f"Error Cant delete data: {table_name} : {error}")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    database_name = "fastapi_test"  
    table_name = 'new_table'
    
    
    read_table(database_name,table_name,'*')
    #insert_table(database_name,table_name,777,'jason','aiot',9487)
```

main.py (fastapi code) , CRUD will success, but receive 422 error.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
from pydantic import BaseModel
from db import get_db_connection,create_db, create_table, insert_table, read_table, update_table, delete_table
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder
app = FastAPI()

class Employee(BaseModel):
    empid:int
    empname: str
    department: str
    salary: int

@app.post("/create_db")
def create_database(db_name: str):
    create_db(db_name)
    return {"message": f"Database {db_name} created successfully"}

@app.post("/create_table")
def create_employee_table(db_name: str, table_name: str):
    create_table(db_name, table_name)
    return {"message": f"Table {table_name} created successfully in database {db_name}"}

@app.post("/insert_employee")
def insert_employee(db_name: str, table_name: str, employee: Employee):
    try:
        insert_table(db_name, table_name, employee.empid,employee.empname, employee.department, employee.salary)
        return {"message": f"Employee {employee.empname} inserted successfully into {table_name}"}
    except Exception as e:
        return {"error": str(e)}

@app.get("/read_employees")
def read_employees(db_name: str, table_name: str, range: str):
    with get_db_connection() as db:
            select = f"""SELECT {range} FROM {db_name}.{table_name}"""
            db.execute(select)
            obj = db.fetchall()
            serialized_data = jsonable_encoder(obj)
            return {"employees": serialized_data}

@app.put("/update_employee")
def update_employee(db_name: str, table_name: str, want_update: str, new_value: int, condition_column: str, condition_value: int):
    update_table(db_name, table_name, want_update, new_value, condition_column, condition_value)
    return {"message": f"Employee updated successfully in {table_name}"}

@app.delete("/delete_employee")
def delete_employee(db_name: str, table_name: str, condition_column: str, condition_value: int):
    delete_table(db_name, table_name, condition_column, condition_value)
    return {"message": f"Employee deleted successfully from {table_name}"}
```

CRUD work and get 200 response, but also get 422 error:(

Answer (score 0):

from your question it is hard to tell which endpoints don't work for you. It would be helpful to provide some more context to it, ex. add POST/GET request that you are sending.

But in general `Validation Error` in FastAPI is raised by Pydantic working under the hood and it means that some of the models/fields that were sent by the request do not match with the expected ones by the given endpoint. If you would like to learn about errors take a look for example at [this](https://medium.com/@roy-pstr/fastapi-server-errors-and-logs-take-back-control-696405437983) article. Good luck :)

Comment: Really thank for your help!!!!! but i still can't solve my problem.
I have post a new detail explain on:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77141015/fastapi-mysql-response-both-200-success-code-422-error-code

can you please help me out, thank a lot.