# FastAPI MySQL response both 200 success code &422 error code

Tags: mysql, fastapi, crud

CRUD can work successfully, however i will also receive 422 codes, but I really don't know why, I think I give the right pydantic schema.

This is  my creatDB.py with some data

```
import mysql.connector


connection = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='localhost',
    user="root",
    password=""
)

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test")

cursor.close()
connection.close()


connection = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='localhost',
    user="root",
    password="",
    database="test"
)
cursor = connection.cursor()


cursor.execute("""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS jason_role (
        role_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        role_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
    )
""")

cursor.execute("""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS jason_user (
    user_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    account VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR(255),
    last_name VARCHAR(255),
    role_name VARCHAR(255),
    project_name_list JSON,  
    account_status INT
    )
""")


cursor.execute("""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS jason_project (
        project_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        project_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        project_user VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
    )
""")


cursor.execute("INSERT INTO role (role_name) VALUES ('supervise')")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO role (role_name) VALUES ('edit')")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO role (role_name) VALUES ('view')")


cursor.execute("""
    INSERT INTO user (account, first_name, last_name, role_name, project_name_list, account_status)
    VALUES ('user1@gmail.com', 'John', 'Doe', 'supervise', '["Project1", "Project2"]', 2)
""")


cursor.execute("""
    INSERT INTO user (account, first_name, last_name, role_name, project_name_list, account_status)
    VALUES ('user2@gmail.com', 'Jane', 'Smith', 'edit', '["Project2", "Project3"]', 2)
""")


cursor.execute("""
    INSERT INTO user (account, first_name, last_name, role_name, project_name_list, account_status)
    VALUES ('user3@gmail.com', 'Alice', 'Johnson', 'view', '["Project1", "Project3"]', 1)
""")


cursor.execute("INSERT INTO project (project_name, project_user) VALUES ('Project1', 'user1')")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO project (project_name, project_user) VALUES ('Project2', 'user2')")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO project (project_name, project_user) VALUES ('Project3', 'user3')")


connection.commit()
cursor.close()
connection.close()

print("Database 'test' and tables created successfully.")
```

This is my schema.py

```
from pydantic import BaseModel,Field


class RoleBase(BaseModel):
    role_id:int
    role_name: str


class UserResponse(BaseModel):
    user_id: int
    account: str
    first_name: str
    last_name: str
    role_name: str
    project_name_list: list[str] 
    account_status: int


class ProjectBase(BaseModel):
    project_id: int
    project_name: str
    project_user: str

class Return7_0(BaseModel):
    role_name : str
    project_name_list: list[str]


class CreateProject(BaseModel):
    project_name: str
    project_user: str
```

Finally, my fastAPI code

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from typing import List
from schema import RoleBase , UserResponse , ProjectBase , Return7_0,  CreateProject
import mysql.connector
import json
app = FastAPI()


connection = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='localhost',
    user="root",
    password="",
    database="test"
)
cursor = connection.cursor()

@app.get("/project_list/", response_model=List[ProjectBase])
async def get_roles():
   
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM project")
    roles = [dict(zip(cursor.column_names, row)) for row in cursor.fetchall()]

    return roles

@app.get("/user_list_all/", response_model=List[UserResponse])
async def get_users():
   
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM user")
    
    users = [dict(zip(cursor.column_names, row)) for row in cursor.fetchall()]

 
    for user in users:
        user["project_name_list"] = json.loads(user["project_name_list"])

    return users
@app.get("/user_list_specific/", response_model=List[Return7_0])
async def get_users():
   
    cursor.execute("SELECT role_name,project_name_list FROM user")
    
    users = [dict(zip(cursor.column_names, row)) for row in cursor.fetchall()]


    for user in users:
        user["project_name_list"] = json.loads(user["project_name_list"])

    return users

@app.get("/role_list/", response_model=List[RoleBase])
async def get_roles():
 
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM role")
    roles = [dict(zip(cursor.column_names, row)) for row in cursor.fetchall()]

    return roles

@app.post("/create_projects/", response_model=List[CreateProject])
async def create_projects(projects: List[CreateProject]):
    created_projects = [] 

    for project in projects:
       
        created_projects.append(project)
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO project (project_name, project_user) VALUES (%s, %s)", (project.project_name, project.project_user))
        connection.commit()
    
    return created_projects
```

as i test in swagger UI , only create_project will receive code 200+422, others are all 200

here is my request body (test case):

```
[
  {
    "project_name": "string",
    "project_user": "string"
  }
]
```

here is the detail error message:

```
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "loc": [
        "string",
        0
      ],
      "msg": "string",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

as i check everythin, i dont really know where is the problem, and how to check this error message :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are checking the right field in the documentation? See below - those are *possible* [responses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVpUN.png) that this endpoint may return, not the response you actually get from calling it. Actual response from the server is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iK5P.png).

I got your code locally, tested it and it works as expected, so if I understood something wrong please let me know.